# How to clone and push changes to remote repository using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

Any idea how to clone a remote repository into local drive, commit changes to it and push the changes to remote repository using libgit2sharp?

Comment: Apologies for the incomplete question. I want to clone a remote repository using libgit2sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how to clone a remote repository into local drive,

- Static method **[Repository.Clone()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs#L540-L575)** will do just that.
- See the **[CloneFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CloneFixture.cs)** test suite for more information about use cases.

> commit changes to it

- Select the updated files you'd like to be part of your next commit using **[repo.Index.Stage()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Index.cs#L130-L183)**, then create a new commit through **[repo.Commit()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/IRepository.cs#L199-L209)**
- See the **[StageFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/StageFixture.cs)** and **[CommitFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CommitFixture.cs)** test suites for more information about use cases.

> and push the changes to remote repository

- Use **[repo.Network.Push()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/Network.cs#L187-L328)** to update a specified remote with your local changes
- See the **[PushFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/PushFixture.cs)** test suite for more information about use cases.